# Running a jar in java liberty app on bluemix

Tags: java, jar, ibm-cloud

I'm using a dialog app in Bluemix, in java. I have another java project, on Elcipse, and to make it simple for me, I decided to turn it into a runnable jar.

So, in my dialog app, I want to run a jar, take the output, and use it. I'm trying to use this, in DemoServlet.java :

```
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("java -jar SomeCoolApp.jar");
```

It is really important that I can use the output of this jar only when my users have a specific behavior.

I got an error :

> App/0Cannot run program "java": error=2, No such file or directory
>   App/0[ERROR ] Service error: Cannot run program "java": error=2, No
>   such file or directory

I understand that I dont understand at all the logic of bluemix. I need help.
This is a part of my bluid.xml :

```
<property name="LIB_DIR" value="./lib" />
<property name="WEB_INF_LIB_DIR" value="./WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
<property name="warname" value="webApp.war" />
<path id="classpathDir">
    <pathelement location="build/bin" />
    <fileset dir="${LIB_DIR}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${WEB_INF_LIB_DIR}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

And in /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib I put my jar, and every jar I need.
I never used the cf command line, I didn't change the manifest.yml. I dont know if or how i should modify it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you not just include the classes from your jar in your built artefacts and invoke the classes? Runtime.exec is a very heavy way to invoke one Java class from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr Bush from IBM I have the answer. Running a jar in Bluemix is hard - I hope this post will be easy to find.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/vcap/app/.java/jre/bin/java", "-jar", "/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/hello.jar");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

Problem 1: java Path
Problem 2: jar Path
Problem 3: Process

Comment: You're welcome Nicolas! I would also like to add that jars need to be moved to the lib folder under the WebContent directory so they are accessible once the packaged server is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify a full path to the `java` executable. Something like the following should work:

```
File javaFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin/java");
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec(javaFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -jar SomeCoolApp.jar");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Already tried this. Not working. The logs are showing an issue with java path, so I'm working on that point. But even with the correct javaPath, I think it's not the only problem